# CakePHP 1.1 "parseExtension" inexsistent

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with a site in CakePHP 1.1 which is impossible to migrate from version due to the size of the project.

I need to create methods to which call using extensions, for example:

```
$Route->connect('/xxx.xml', array ('controller' => 'Interactive', 'action' => 'xxx'));
```

But this does not work and the problem is that Cake 1.1 does not have this function:

```
Router::parseExtensions('xml');
```

Has anyone working with cakephp 1.1 had this problem? If so do they know how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% familiar of the capabilities of CakePHP 1.1, but have you considered setting up a router to look for something like the following:

```
/:controller/:action.xml
```

Then you could control what controller/action it leads to and alter the layout.

You might need to escape the . on .xml.

I would seriously consider upgrading to CakePHP 1.3 and reading the migration docs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the layout, is this:

if i set this router:

```
$Route->connect('/xxx.xml', array ('controller' => 'Interactive', 'action' => 'xxx'));
```

or your example:

```
$Route->connect('/:controller/:xxx.xml', array ('controller' => 'Interactive', 'action' => 'xxx'));
```

the function called is:

```
class MuControlController extends AppController {
   function xxx.xml() {
   }
```

obiusly this function cant exists.